# What is the priority of the `library of babel' code blocks versus the named code blocks locally in `org-babel-expand-noweb-references'?

Tags: org-babel

When tangling my literate files, code blocks from the `library of babel`, added using `org-babel-lob-ingest`, are overriding local named code blocks. I'd thought it's supposed to be the other way around. If that's not the case, where can I find more information on the priority of the code blocks used?

UPDATE: Upon request, I have summarized the steps to reproduce this below:

`ingest.org:`

```
#+name: 826ab469-eeef-4392-aec9-4dd490409430
#+begin_src text
Hello,
#+end_src
```

`test.org:`

```
#+name: 826ab469-eeef-4392-aec9-4dd490409430
#+begin_src text
Goodbye,
#+end_src

#+begin_src text :tangle test.txt :noweb yes
<<826ab469-eeef-4392-aec9-4dd490409430>> world!
#+end_src
```

Run `chmod +x org-tangle && ./org-tangle test.org` using the `org-tangle` script [here](https://pastebin.com/ScLcu7XA), modeled after [`doomemacs'`](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/bin/org-tangle) own script, but with `(org-babel-lob-ingest "ingest.org")` included. The file `test.txt` will be tangled, but with `Hello, world!` instead of `Goodbye, world!`.

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this problem? Please provide a complete, minimal example.

Comment: Sorry about that; the process was a little more complicated than I anticipated! Will my current update suffice?

Comment: No - I get an error and backtrace (which I've mostly elided): `$ ./org-tangle test.org
1 source block added to Library of Babel

Error: wrong-type-argument (listp "Goodbye, world!")
  mapbacktrace(#f(compiled-function (evald func args flags) #<bytecode 0x9da9dec51aef0c2>))
  debug-early-backtrace()
  debug-early(error (wrong-type-argument listp "Goodbye, world!")) ........ 
  command-line--load-script("/tmp/foo/org-tangle")
  command-line-1(("-scriptload" "./org-tangle" "--" "test.org"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
Wrong type argument: listp, "Goodbye, world!"`

Comment: If I visit `test.org` and do `M-x org-babel-lob-ingest RET ingest.org` and then do `C-c C-v C-t` on the code block, I do get a `test.txt` which contains: `Goodbye, world!`. You need to simplify that script (which is hardly minimal).

Comment: Interesting... I wonder why the script works on my system, especially since the script is meant to work without a user's `init.el` or `early-init.el`... I only know the basics of how the script works, unfortunately; I'm not sure I can simplify it without it ceasing to function entirely. Actually, could the `org-mode` version be the issue, here, regarding the script failing? The default version for `emacs 27.2` seems to be `9.4.4`.